# The effect op graph operations on the chromatic number (Papers/Books)

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

Can anyone please direct me to a paper or even a textbook which would provide a good read on how graph operations influence the chromatic number of a graph?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could be more specific about what you mean by graph operations. It seems that there is [a lot of them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_operations).

Comment: Hi Martin, sorry I meant basic operations like the union (maximum chi of the 2 graphs, so that's simple), join, and products of graphs. Perhaps also the subdivision of a graph.